# MPI: Binary tree topology with variable number of processes

Tags: graph, mpi, binary-tree

I want to use the *MPI_Graph_create()* function to build a virtual topology - specifically a balanced binary tree. When working with a fixed number of processes i can take pen and paper and just work on the neighbours and edges of each process and fill the two parameters *indx* and *edges* accordingly.

But say i have a variable number of processes. For example 6 in this case:
[image]

I can't come up with an idea of how to dynamically calculate the neighbours and edges of each process and how to fill the parameters *indx* and *edges* of the *MPI_Graph_create()* function.

I appreciate any tip on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Is it essential that the children of `2` be `4` and `6` rather than  `4` and `5` ?

Comment: It's not really essential for me how the processes are organized as long as the resulting tree is balanced.

Comment: In that case get your pencil and paper out and start writing down the adjacency matrix for the graph.  The pattern, and the necessary arithmetic, emerges.

Comment: Thanks alot for the tip. I can see the "two right, one down" pattern in the x direction now which is mirrored at the diagonal axis. So i should be able to put the math together tomorrow and fill the parameters accordingly.